# Laravel 5.1 update many-to-many pivot

Tags: php, many-to-many, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot

I'm trying to update records on a pivot table using Eloquent in Laravel 5.1.

I've got 3 tables: `pages`, `resources` and the pivot `pages_resources`. These are the relationship methods:

Model Page.php

```
public function resources()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Resource', 'pages_resources', 'id_page', 'id_resource')
                ->orderBy('ordering', 'asc');
}
```

Model Resource.php

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Page', 'pages_resources', 'id_resource', 'id_page');
}
```

Now, I'm getting a list of resources from an AJAX POST request, and I want to change their order. I'm using a `findMany` method to fetch the collection:

```
$resources = Resource::with('page')->findMany($request->get('order'));
$resources->each(function ($item, $key) {
   // Working on $item here
});
```

and here is where I'm stumped. I tried both `sync()`

```
  $item->page()->sync([$item->id => ['ordering' => $key+1]], false));
```

and `updateExistingPivot()`

```
 $item->page()->updateExistingPivot($item->id, ['ordering' => $key+1], false);
```

and while the former yields wrong results the latter isn't event working (no error message received, though. It simply fails silently);

Using sync() always ends up creating a new record in the pivot table, with the correct value for the "ordering" column but wrong value for the keys. I tried using something different then $item->id (which maps to "id_resource"), but to no avail.

I might have done something wrong, though the relationships look correct, since a Resource object has a

```
#relations: array:1 [
    "page" =>
```

collection, and the page collection in turn shows the pivot:

```
#relations: array:1 [
            "pivot" => Pivot {#318
```

How can I update a pivot table record?

Comment: Could you try $page->id instead of $item->id for the first parameter of `updateExistingPivot`? That's how it is in the documentation.